# Unity 2D repeating overworld

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

What is the best way to implement an endlessly scrolling overworld in Unity? I currently have a map cut into 4 different prefabs and as the player moves and reaches the edge of one of the prefabs, the part of the map that should be next will pop into existence. Also, when the player gets far enough away from a map piece, the piece will suddenly disappear as to save on computing resources.

I've also thought of making it *seem* like the player is moving, but instead actually move the world around the player. So the player will stay at 0x and 0y but it's the map that moves while the player just does his animation.

I have a feeling there's a better way to go about doing this. If anyone could let me in on some game dev secrets, I would appreciate it.

Comment: It depends of gameplay/graphics/camera mode/map size etc. Type what do you exactly mean

Comment: https://kotaku.com/classic-jrpg-worlds-are-actually-donuts-1239882216

Comment: A large flat 2D overworld map. The kind you would see in an SNES RPG. Like Chrono Trigger or Final Fantasy. Not the kind you would see in Seiken Densetsu though. Seiken Densetsu is like 2D trying to be 3D, which was pretty cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used repeating of coords for this

```
public MapChunk GetChunk (int x, int y)
{
    x = (int)Mathf.Repeat(x, WorldSizeX);
    y = (int)Mathf.Repeat(y, WorldSizeY);
    //Then using map chunk map[x, y]
    if (map[x, y] == null)
    {
        //For example, you can create chunks lazy (only when calls)
        GameObject block = Instantiate(ChunkPrefab);
    }
    return map[x, y];
}
```

Comment: So you would move your player character along the x and y and instantiate prefabs according to how close or far the player character is to the edge of the prefab that he's currently in? My only concern with this is if the player decides to keep moving in the same direction for too long. I believe Unity begins to give problems if the x or y coordinates are too large.

Comment: Unity uses float point for coords - if your map is so large - just keep your player near world zero (for example you can move everything around player with player itself every x seconds)

Comment: It means you had to make an additional offset and use it for keepeng accuracy (I don't think you really need it, It's very hard to reach non-accuracy float point distances if you make your player a little smaller

Comment: hmm and I can just keep a reference of which prefabs are currently instantiated and their coordinates for when the player enters a town or something. Then when they come back out of the town, I can re-instantiate those prefabs and the proper locations. Sound like the most logical way to do it. I just wondered if there was possibly a better way. Thanks man :)